# Why does Alfresco Explorer 3.4e CE show no Login form, when deployed in Glassfish 3.1.1?

Tags: java, jsp, glassfish, alfresco

I just deployed alfresco.war into Glassfish 3.1.1. After that, I saw that the login page is white except the background image, no login form is show.

I viewed the HTML source and I saw that the form  was not rendered.
The log file didn't log anything about that (no exceptions).

What is the problem, and how to solve that?

Please note that I tested to deploy "Alfresco Explorer 3.4d CE" instead, and everything seemed to be good, I was able to login and add contents etc.

Comment: Did you try following the instructions in the [Alfresco on Glassfish wiki](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_on_Glassfish)?

Comment: Yes, As I said the "d" version is work, but I solved the problem now, you can find the solution in first answer now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I solved it, The problem seems the conflicts between Glassfish bundled JSF with alfresco bundled, that the cause of JSF tags not rendered, so I solved that by adding "sun-web.xml" file inside "WEB-INF" folder with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE sun-web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.0 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://www.sun.com/software/appserver/dtds/sun-web-app_3_0-0.dtd">
<sun-web-app>
    <class-loader delegate="false"/>
    <property name="useBundledJsf" value="true"/>
    <property name="useMyFaces" value="true"/>
</sun-web-app>
```

the solution key is in :

```
<property name="useBundledJsf" value="true"/>
```

Regards,